# How to display the array in reverse order in Android

Tags: android, arrays, string, reverse

Hi I have created a database and displayed the contents in list view. I need to display the contents from last to first record. Here is my code:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from TABLE", null);

String[] array = new String[c.getCount()];
int i = c.getCount();
if (c.moveToLast())
{
    do 
    {
        String uname = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("product_name"));               
        array[i] = uname;
        i--;
    }
    while (c.moveToPrevious()) ;
}
```

I have stored the column "product_name " in a string array. In order to print the column in reverse order this is the code I have tried. Application stopped unfortunately. Can anyone say where did I go wrong?

Comment: Is this Java?  C#?  You need to tag your question with the language you're using.

Comment: Android is not a programming language; it's an operating system. It's necessary when asking code related questions for you to include a language tag (Java, C#, or whichever other tag applies to the language you're using). If you can't name the language, you're probably not ready to start programming using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time you post to Stackoverflow, include the debug information (stack trace, etc).  That said, it appears you're accessing your string at a bad index.

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from TABLE", null);

String[] array = new String[c.getCount()];
//Start i at c.getCount() - 1, indices are zero based.
int i = c.getCount() - 1;
if (c.moveToLast())
{
    do 
    {
        String uname = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("product_name"));               
        array[i] = uname;
        i--;
    }
    while (c.moveToPrevious()) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to sort the items you can use [ORDER BY](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_order_by.htm). 
Lets say you want to order the items from the last to first based on the id you can use `ORDER BY id DESC` and this will order all the items in the descending order. You can then iterate through them like you normally would.